# Pass data from child to parent and to another child component React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am passing props from a child component B to parent component A. And then from parent component A passing it to child component C. When I'm passing the data from component B to A it is all fine. But when I try to set a state to data received from component B in parent Component A the state is not being set immediately.

I have binded the functions in all the components.

Below is the code of function I'm using.

In component A:

```
onchange=(data) => {
this.setState({
  selectedvalue: data
});
console.log(data)
console.log(this.state.selectedvalue)
}
```

On the initial render I get the correct value in `console.log(data)` but receive `undefied` in `console.log(this.state.selectedvalue)`. When the data is changed `console.log(this.state.selectedvalue)` displays the initial value `console.log(data)` has shown. i.e the state is being set after an interaction and not at the same time.

I want to pass the attribute `selectedvalue` to another child component C.

But with the state not being set instantly I'm unable to pass the data the moment it is changed.

Is there any way how I can pass the data from child component B to child component C through parent component A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState` is async, you can access the updated value in the [`callback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

```
this.setState({
  selectedvalue: data
}, () => console.log(this.state.selectedvalue));
```

If you pass `this.state.selectedvalue` to the child component as a prop, the child component will automatically be re-rendered with the updated value whenever `this.state.selectedvalue` changes (unless you explicitly ignore it with `shouldComponentUpdate`).